# wandb.sdk.wandb_manager.ManagerConnectionRefusedError: Connection to wandb service failed: [WinError 10061]

Tags: git, pytorch, yolo, yolov5, wandb

I have a problem about AI project use yolov5 and WandB.

Developing Environment has packages include

code:

```
import os
os.environ["KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK"]="TRUE"

!python train.py --data data/blood_cell.yaml --batch-size 4 --epochs 300 --img-size 640 --project runs/train --name JHP --weights weights/yolov5s.pt --device cpu --cache WANDB__SERVICE_WAIT=300
```

result:

```
wandb: WARNING  wandb is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. See supported integrations at https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5#integrations.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\JHP\lib\site-packages\wandb\sdk\wandb_manager.py", line 117, in _service_connect
    svc_iface._svc_connect(port=port)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\JHP\lib\site-packages\wandb\sdk\service\service_sock.py", line 30, in _svc_connect
    self._sock_client.connect(port=port)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\JHP\lib\site-packages\wandb\sdk\lib\sock_client.py", line 102, in connect
    s.connect(("localhost", port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] 대상 컴퓨터에서 연결을 거부했으므로 연결하지 못했습니다

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\JHP\yolov5\train.py", line 56, in <module>
    from utils.loggers import Loggers
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\JHP\yolov5\utils\loggers\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    wandb_login_success = wandb.login(timeout=30)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\JHP\lib\site-packages\wandb\sdk\wandb_login.py", line 74, in login
    if wandb.setup()._settings._noop:
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\JHP\lib\site-packages\wandb\sdk\wandb_setup.py", line 327, in setup
    ret = _setup(settings=settings)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\JHP\lib\site-packages\wandb\sdk\wandb_setup.py", line 320, in _setup
    wl = _WandbSetup(settings=settings)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\JHP\lib\site-packages\wandb\sdk\wandb_setup.py", line 303, in __init__
    _WandbSetup._instance = _WandbSetup__WandbSetup(settings=settings, pid=pid)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\JHP\lib\site-packages\wandb\sdk\wandb_setup.py", line 114, in __init__
    self._setup()
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\JHP\lib\site-packages\wandb\sdk\wandb_setup.py", line 250, in _setup
    self._setup_manager()
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\JHP\lib\site-packages\wandb\sdk\wandb_setup.py", line 277, in _setup_manager
    self._manager = wandb_manager._Manager(settings=self._settings)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\JHP\lib\site-packages\wandb\sdk\wandb_manager.py", line 164, in __init__
    sentry_reraise(e, delay=True)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\JHP\lib\site-packages\wandb\util.py", line 214, in sentry_reraise
    raise exc.with_traceback(sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\JHP\lib\site-packages\wandb\sdk\wandb_manager.py", line 162, in __init__
    self._service_connect()
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\JHP\lib\site-packages\wandb\sdk\wandb_manager.py", line 126, in _service_connect
    raise ManagerConnectionRefusedError(message)
wandb.sdk.wandb_manager.ManagerConnectionRefusedError: Connection to wandb service failed: [WinError 10061] 대상 컴퓨터에서 연결을 거부했으므로 연결하지 못했습니다.
```

**"대상 컴퓨터에서 연결을 거부했으므로 연결하지 못했습니다." means "Connection failed because the destination computer refused the connection."**

I try to find posts from people who have experienced the same problem by googling.
I've actually found a few cases and followed that solution, but it didn't work.
(I tried the following solutions → [https://github.com/wandb/wandb/issues/1236, https://github.com/wandb/wandb/issues/1016, https://github.com/wandb/wandb/issues/4224])

I've already tried downgrading the version of the WandB package. The connection was successful, but the learning stopped with instructions to upgrade the version of WandB package.

I suspect this issue is caused by git, and there have been a few instances where the operating system displayed an error message for the conhost.exe process just before the issue occurred

Another issue was resolved immediately before this issue occurred, and the issue and solution are as shown on https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/1532 and https://github.com/taesungp/contrastive-unpaired-translation/issues/52

+)
[A new symptom was identified in the same error. An error message for git.exe was displayed just like when an error message for conhost.exe was displayed. "응용 프로그램을 제대로 시작하지 못했습니다(0xc0000142). 응용 프로그램을 닫으려면 확인을 클릭하십시오" means **"Failed to start application properly (0xc0000142). Click OK to close the application"**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9e2j.png)

Comment: Can you share code to help reproduce this issue please

Comment: The error disappeared suddenly. Honestly, I'm worried, but anyway, learning goes normally. It was probably a problem caused by a temporary communication error. After that, there was an error (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/the-paging-file-is-too-small-for-this-operation-to/e62356fd-5bae-4fdf-ad1c-0b2824ba8aa7) related to the paging file, but fortunately, it was resolved (https://velog.io/@youngs508/GetLastError-returned-1455-이-작업을-완료하기-위한-페이징-파일이-너무-작습니다). If you need a full code, I'll provide it.

Comment: Glad to hear it was resolved. That's very strange.